# How do import / export work in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am learning the ES6 standard so I start from a very basic example code.

My first file is `Rectangle.js`

```
class Rectangle {
  perimeter(x, y) {
    return (2 * (x + y));
  }
  area(x, y) {
    return (x * y);
  }
}

export default class { Rectangle };
```

And in another file `solve-1.js`, I have some imports like this

```
import Rectangle from './Rectangle';

function solveRect(l, b) {
  if (l < 0 || b < 0) {
    console.log(`Rectangle dimensions should be greater than zero:  l = ${l} and b = ${b}`);
  } else {
    console.log(Rectangle.area(l, b));
  }
}

solveRect(2, 4);
```

I am using babel-node to run this program, I do have required presets installed, my `.babelrc` contains

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

The reported error info was

```
/Users/Kulbear/Desktop/NodeBear/Basic/solve-1.js:13
    console.log(_Rectangle2.default.area(l, b));
                                    ^

TypeError: _Rectangle2.default.area is not a function
    at solveRect (solve-1.js:7:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (solve-1.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at loader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:148:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:160:24
```

Edit:

```
$ node --version
> v6.3.1
```

Comment: Might be useful to read some documentation about the new ES6 features, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. This line:

   ```
   export default class { Rectangle };
   ```

   ...is trying to create a *new* class somehow containing `Rectangle`. It would fail to compile, but you've included Stage 2 in your `.babelrc` and so Babel thinks it's an attempt to create a [field](http://jeffmo.github.io/es-class-public-fields/). I think you probably want:

   ```
   export default Rectangle;
   ```
2. You have no `Rectangle.area(l, b)`. You've defined `area` as a method of `Rectangle` *instances*, not as a static method. Either change it to a static:

   ```
   static area() {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   **or** when you use it, use an *instance*

   ```
   var r = new Rectangle();
   r.area(/*...*/);
   ```

   From the code, you want the `static`.

So taking those two things and putting them together (I made `perimeter` `static` as well):

`Rectangle.js`:

```
class Rectangle {
  static perimeter(x, y) {
    return (2 * (x + y));
  }
  static area(x, y) {
    return (x * y);
  }
}

export default Rectangle;
```

`solve-1.js`:

```
import Rectangle from './Rectangle';

function solveRect(l, b) {
  if (l < 0 || b < 0) {
    console.log(`Rectangle dimensions should be greater than zero:  l = ${l} and b = ${b}`);
  } else {
    console.log(Rectangle.area(l, b));
  }
}
solveRect(2, 4);
```

Works:

```
$ babel-node solve-1.js 
8
```

---

A couple of side notes:

1. If you like, you can combine the export and class declaration:

   ```
     export default class Rectangle {
         // ...implementaton
     }
   ```

   Note that it's a declaraion, so unlike other exports, it doesn't end with `;` ([handy reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#table-42); although including one is harmless).
2. If `Rectangle` *only* has `static` methods, there's no reason for it to be a class at all; just use named exports of your static functions:

   ```
   export function perimeter {
       // ...
   }
   export function area {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Then people importing can use named import syntax if they just want one of those:

   ```
   import area from './Rectangle';
   ```

   ...and if they want all of them, they can use a namespace import:

   ```
   import * as Rectangle from './Rectangle';
   ```

   and then use `Rectangle.area` or such.

   E.g., it gives the user of the module flexibility.

Comment: Read it again at this moment, and it's really an elaborative answer, thanks!-

Answer (score 5):

As *T.J.* already said, the following line does not really makes sense:

```
export default class { Rectangle };
```

**But** it is valid JS. What you're actually doing is exporting an anonymous `class` that has as property `"Rectangle"` and the value of this property is the constructor for your previously defined `class Rectangle`.

So when you import the above you would have to do the following to have it work properly:

```
import Rectangle from './Rectangle';

const rect1 = new Rectangle();
const rect2 = new rect1.Rectangle();
rect2.area(5,5);
```

Of course this is not really what you wanted to do. What you actually want is:

```
export default Rectangle;
```

Also, it seems like you just want some methods rather than construction a whole class. At least in your example you're not creating an instance of the `Rectangle` object.

If this is the case I would suggest you remove the class and do something like this:

```
export function perimeter (x, y) {
  return (2 * (x + y));
}
export function area(x, y) {
  return (x * y);
}
```

Then you can do the following to import and use the defined methods:

```
import * as Rectangle from './Rectangle';
console.log(Rectangle.area(5,5));
```

Comment: Well, it will be valid in ES2017 (and is valid for the OP, as they've included Stage 2).

Comment: Never said it was invalid ES :) I tried to explain what his code actually does.

Comment: No, you said it was *valid*. I'm semi-joking that it *will be* valid in ES2017 (and is valid for the OP because they've included Stage 2 in their `.babelrc`), but isn't valid *now*. Sorry if it didn't come off. :-)

Comment: I c :-) For me no sane person is writing ES5 anymore anyway ;D

Comment: Thanks man your explanation made a lot of sense. Just one point, and it is what I just read is that never use * for import. Ref [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--no-wildcard)

Comment: *"For me no sane person is writing ES5 anymore anyway"* Well, yes, but `class { Rectangle; }` isn't valid ES2015 or ES2016 either. That's my point.

Comment: Thanks T.J. actually thought it is! @Kulbear: That's what the Airbnb styleguide says, yes :)